# Split speaker-level output

Tags: audio, speakers

I've got powered output (from a Sonos ZonePlayer 120, aka Connect:Amp) which I'd like to send to two different sets of speakers. Young me might have just split the speaker wires, but I'd rather not lose power/fidelity.

Searching around, it's maybe a distribution amplifier that I want, but the ones I saw seem like they expect line level signals.

It would be nice to be able to set the levels of the two sets of speakers separately, but it isn't crucial. Maybe just a power amp with two outputs would do the trick.

What's my best bet here?

Answer (score 2):

Use a distribution amplifier and put a variable attenuator inline after each send.  This will allow you to control the volume of each line level output.  You might also be able to find a DA with built in level control.  A DA is absolutely what you want for this case though.

Note that you could also use a DA and send the same level feed to two different power amps (one for each set of speakers) and adjust the power on each power amp.

Update: Sorry, missed you said it was a powered output.  For a powered output, you just wire them up in a chain.  This is the way speaker stacks are wired as well as the way stage monitors are wired.  It shouldn't be a problem with a powered signal.

Comment: Again, I don't have line level at all. I just have powered speaker outputs.

Comment: In a chain? So in series (on each channel)?

Comment: But then there's no way to adjust the levels on each either, right?

Comment: @Grumdrig - you could wire the sets in parallel and put attenuators on each circuit.  As far as series vs parallel, I'm having trouble remembering which way chainable speakers do it.  Most of the speakers I work with have two jacks, one for in and one to go to the next speaker, but I seem to remember hearing at one point that internally it is wired in parallel across the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I found this "speaker switcher":

[http://www.amazon.com/4-ZONE-Speaker-Selector-Switcher-Control/dp/B003ED2DZA/ref=sr_1_6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ED2DZA)

It seems like it might be what I want.

Comment: Haha. It's "600 Watt" because you are welcome to pump 600 watts through it if you'd like. It's an unpowered speaker selector, but it does have attenuation. I'll probably just use it though.